# main manifest lacks a <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion> declaration beign ignored

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm receiving the message `main manifest lacks a <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion> declaration` despite the existence of it on the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
               android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>


<permission
    android:name=".permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

I already tried to remove and rebuild the application but i've got no success

Update: 
Gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you're using Gradle, make sure all the variables are set properly

Comment: In gradle I have `minSdkVersion 14` set inside `defaultConfig`

Comment: The error does NOT state minSdkVersion is missing, it says `targetSdkVersion` is missing. In plain text too. Try invalidating the caches and restarting

Comment: You are right Zoe, I missread the error... I've included the line but the error persists, even after a Invalidate Caches and Restarting

Comment: take a look at the merged manifest - is it included there?

Comment: I can't find it anywhere... Is there any default path it should be?

Comment: It's a separate tab when you open the manifest. If it doesn't contain the variables, that means there's a merge fail somewhere, and it's most likely a bug or some other factor I'm not seeing. If they are there, run `./gradlew` to manually build from the command line - AS some times hides errors with other, less descriptive and in reality nested errors rather than showing the actual issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190531/discussion-between-andre-santarosa-and-zoe).